# Silverlight 4 HttpWebRequest throwing ProtocolViolationException

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0, httpwebrequest

I'm invoking a REST service via http which returns a stream as the response.
My client code looks like so:

```
                Uri uri = new Uri(remoteAddress);
                var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                webRequest.Method = "GET";
                webRequest.ContentType = "multipart/mixed";
                webRequest.BeginGetResponse(responseResult =>
                {
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(responseResult);
                    this.messages = ParseResponse(response);
                    Complete(false);
                }, null);
```

I'm getting the following error on this line:

```
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(responseResult);
```

System.Net.ProtocolViolationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
       at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at LaharSubProxy.SubscribeAsyncResult`1.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IAsyncResult responseResult)
       at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__b(Object state2)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
  InnerException:

This is driving me absolutely nuts since the exception is not pointing to anything useful. I have enabled the "streaming" option in fiddler but I'm not seeing any traffic/errors.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well whatdya know, the problem is this line:

```
webRequest.ContentType = "multipart/mixed";
```

Seems like this is a SL bug/nuance. I commented that line out and the error disappears!
I should also add that the code as is works just fine in a traditional console/windows app.

[This post](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/17519.aspx) pointed me the right direction. Thanks Microsoft!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the ContentType property implies that you are going to provide a message body with your request. It would seem that the .net libraries don't want to allow this, though I can find nothing in the HTTP spec to suggest that it should be fobidden.